# Check radio button whose value = $ programmatically

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, radio-button

There is a radio button group define as below:

```
<input type="radio" name="type0" value="$">$<input type="radio" name="type0" value="%">%
```

Need to check the first radio button whose value = `$`.

The problem is the below code doesn't accomplish this. Need some way of escaping `$`

```
$('input[type=radio][value=$]').attr('checked','checked');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('input[type=radio][value="$"]').first().attr('checked','checked');
```

Comment: -1 because this solution will check **all** radio buttons with value = $, not just the **first**, like he asked for.

Comment: The actual question was "some way of escaping the $" by I've changed the answer anyway

Answer (score 2):

this works for me, enclose the selector in double quotes and the attribute selector in single ones

```
$("input[type=radio][value='$']").attr('checked','checked');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BuvKT/

Comment: -1 because this solution will check **all** radio buttons with value = $, not just the **first**, like he asked for.

Comment: @drrcknlsn ah! right, but the question was to how to escape the `$`

Comment: True enough, but if he has multiple radio groups like this on one page, the code you're using (and the code he tried to use) will select all of them with value = $.  That's probably not the desired effect.  And even if this is the only group like it on the page, it can prevent future bugs to qualify it using `:first` or `.first()` and/or specify the group name in the selector `[name="type0"]`.

Comment: @drrcknlsn yes "**probably** not the desired effect"!

Answer (score 2):

Escape dollar with `\\`:

```
$('input[type=radio][value=\\$]:first').attr('checked','checked');
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/E6uBw/3/

Comment: -1 because this solution will check **all** radio buttons with value = $, not just the **first**, like he asked for.

Comment: First means the first from 2 mentinoed.

Comment: What part of "Need to check the first radio button whose value = $" leads you to believe he only wanted the first of the two mentioned?

Comment: Code above this sentence. Anyway, I've added `.first()` to remove missunderstainding. Thanks.

Comment: I guess you're right; it could be interpreted either way.  Removed the -1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="radio"][name="type0"][value="$"]:first').prop('checked', true);
```